# Tensorflow Multi-threaded QueueRunner

Tags: multithreading, tensorflow

I have a graph:

```
                                     - preprocessing_op1 -> op2 -> img
                                    /                                 \
slice_input_producer([imgs, labels])                              tf.train.batch(num_threads=n)
                                    \- - - - - - - label - - - - - - -/
```

which is a typical Data I/O pipeline.

Problem: The multiple threads for tf.train.batch() have a race condition.
e.g. Thread1 fetches sample1_img and sample2_label because Thread2 already took sample1_label, making a pair (sample1_img, sample2_label). I guess this is because slice_input_producer has 2 separate queues for imgs and labels and two queues work independently.

Q1. Does each of n enqueueing threads run its own replica of the subgraph? If yes, setting num_threads=n requires n times more memory for the corresponding subgraph in runtime? If no, do threads run the different part of the subgraph for one enqueue op?

Q2 (solved). If I create a FIFOQueue and enqueue a tuple of (img, label), the pair will be atomically dequeued and multi-threading will actually help. Is this correct? (although it's not 100% utilization because label tensor waits for the preprocessing of img tensor)

Q3 (solved). Is there a function like tuple_input_producer() which takes a list of tensors and internally use only one queue?

---

**Update** (Q2,Q3)

I was wrong about slice_input_tensor.
The problem only happens with two queues, not with slice_input_producer.

So just use slice_input_producer, and if two tensors need to go into different queues, I can use a single-threaded bottleneck (QueueRunner) to bundle them together.

Example code (0.11):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

a = tf.train.string_input_producer(map(str,range(100)), shuffle=False).dequeue()
b = tf.train.string_input_producer(map(str,range(100)), shuffle=False).dequeue()
op1 = tf.identity(a)
op2 = tf.identity(op1)
c1, c2 = tf.train.batch([op2,b], num_threads=10, batch_size=10)

with tf.Session() as sess, tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    sess.run([tf.initialize_all_variables()])

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess, coord)

    for i in range(10):
        d1, d2 = sess.run([c1,c2])
        print d1, d2

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Result (see the first line):

```
['0' '2' '1' '7' '4' '3' '6' '8' '9' '5'] ['0' '2' '1' '6' '5' '4' '7' '8' '9' '3']
['10' '11' '12' '13' '14' '15' '16' '17' '18' '19'] ['10' '11' '12' '13' '14' '15' '16' '17' '18' '19']
['20' '21' '22' '23' '24' '25' '26' '27' '28' '29'] ['20' '21' '22' '23' '24' '25' '26' '27' '28' '29']
['30' '31' '33' '32' '34' '35' '36' '37' '38' '39'] ['30' '31' '33' '32' '34' '35' '36' '37' '38' '39']
['40' '41' '42' '43' '44' '45' '46' '47' '48' '49'] ['40' '41' '42' '43' '44' '45' '46' '47' '48' '49']
['50' '51' '52' '53' '54' '55' '56' '57' '58' '59'] ['50' '51' '52' '53' '54' '55' '56' '57' '58' '59']
['60' '61' '62' '63' '64' '65' '66' '67' '68' '69'] ['60' '61' '62' '63' '64' '65' '66' '67' '68' '69']
['70' '71' '72' '73' '74' '75' '76' '77' '78' '79'] ['70' '71' '72' '73' '74' '75' '76' '77' '78' '79']
['80' '81' '82' '83' '84' '85' '86' '87' '88' '89'] ['80' '81' '82' '83' '84' '85' '86' '88' '89' '87']
['90' '91' '92' '93' '94' '95' '96' '97' '98' '99'] ['90' '91' '92' '93' '94' '95' '96' '97' '98' '99']
```

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thank you, updated the answer. Even if it weren't true, it wouldn't break the examples because the race condition is rare and it only hurts the accuracy by a few points. (Mismatched samples can be considered noisy samples)

Comment: OK, that is a bit of a foot-gun. I've put a simpler example that reproduces the behavior [here](https://github.com/yaroslavvb/stuff/blob/master/queue_mismatch.py), it's the same in all TF versions, let me think of a good work-around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have parallel run calls, called "steps", and each step maintains their own copy of tensors produced during execution. So in the worst case you need N times more memory for N parallel steps. In practice it tends to be better than times N because memory is released as soon as tensor is not needed anymore. Stateful objects like queues and variables are shared across steps.

What's happening in your case is the following scenario:

```
step1: dequeue queue1
step2: dequeue queue1
step2: dequeue queue2
step1: dequeue queue2
```

You can see that queues get out of sync for both steps. Two ways to avoid it:

1. Don't issue parallel run calls (num_threads=1)
2. Combine two queues into a single queue with images/labels, and dequeue from that queue in parallel.

In the second example you would have a single `dequeue` op return a pair of `image/label`, and things should stay synchronized because `dequeues` are atomic

Comment: there are plans to add some locking mechanisms in the future that may affect solutions here,  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/6360

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your Update's example code with tf=0.12.1

when the iteration changes from range(10) to range(100), the mismatch also happend.

If I modified the `tf.train.batch` parameter with num_threads=1, it solved.

I've not tried `Combine two queues into a single queue with images/labels, and dequeue from that queue in parallel.` yet.

Comment: The mismatch is supposed to happen with num_threads>1 because the code has two independent dequeue ops (2xstring_input_producer).
A solution is to use a single `slice_input_producer` that gives you one atomic dequeue_op.